# Enumerableのメソッドの.Zip()メソッドでこの場合の動作について知りたい。

Tags: c#

マイクロソフトのリファレンスを見ながらコードを読んでいたのですが`data.Zip(data.Skip(1),(i,j) => j - i);`の[`(i,j) => j - i`]の動作はメソッド内部でどのような処理がなされているのか知りたいです。リファレンスを見てもはっきりしないのでご教授お願いします。
※ラムダ式であることは理解してます。
.zip() https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
class Program 
    {              
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = Enumerable.Range(0,10);
            foreach(var t in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            var data2 = data.Zip(data.Skip(1),(i,j) => j - i);
            foreach(var i in data2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[(i,j) => j - i]のZip内部での呼び出され方は次のリンク先のソースコードに記述されています。
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Zip.cs#L65

引数で渡したラムダ式は次のようなメソッドを表していて、

```
int LambdaFunction(int i, int j)
{
    return j - i;
}
```

それがZipの中では、

```
 using (IEnumerator<int> e1 = data.GetEnumerator())
 using (IEnumerator<int> e2 = data.Skip(1).GetEnumerator())
 {
     while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
     {
         yield return LambdaFunction(e1.Current, e2.Current);
     }
 }
```

のように呼び出されているイメージです。
誤解を恐れずにZipの部分を展開して書くと次のようなイメージです。
正確ではないですが同じ出力結果になります。

```
var data      = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
var dataSkip1 = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

for (int k = 0; k < data.Length && k < dataSkip1.Length; k++) {
    int i = data[k];
    int j = dataSkip1[k];
    yield return j - i;
}
```

参考：内部的な動作がドキュメントから読み取れない場合は、実際のソースコードを読んでみることをお勧めします。.NETCoreでの実装は上のリンクのようにGithubで見ることができますし、[ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)などの逆コンパイラツールを使うと自分が書いたコードから内部の実装に辿っていくこともできますよ。

Comment: 実際、コードを書いてみて実行したのですが=>のラムダ式の部分でコードが読めなくて困っています。i,jがどうなっていうのかが知りたいです。

Comment: ラムダ式の部分について説明を追記してみましたが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: 質問ですが、int LambdaFunction(int i, int j)部のint i,int jの部分がdataの各要素を一番最初からやっているという意味でよろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: iはdataの各要素、jはdata.Skip(1)の各要素を一番最初からやっている、ということになります。回答も少し追記してみました。